# How to invoke jQuery function on document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to do something once `HTML` is loaded and document get ready. However, code doesn't seems to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="dataprocess"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if( $('div').hasClass('dataprocess') ) {
     console.log('working');
   }
});
```

Not able to get `working` on console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/1142/

Comment: Make sure you close the ready function using `});`

Comment: You are missing the closing syntax of the doc ready function. Typo. Voting to close.

Comment: Check for errors in browser dev tools console (F12). Probably seeing syntax error there which is a big clue. ALso helpful to include error messages in question if there are any

Comment: I didind copy the closing part now I edited it

Comment: It's not the problem

Comment: Is JQuery included in the HTML file? How are you including the Javascript file?

Comment: You must not have referenced JQuery because the code does work when it's referenced. Still falls under the typo category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your snippet, you're missing the closing brackets for the `$(document).ready()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('div').hasClass('dataprocess')){
        console.log('working');
    }
});
```

This is the only visible issue in your code.

Also some other things you may have forgotten:

- Include the JavaScript file
- Include the jQuery dependency

Comment: We generally don't answer questions that have simple typos as the problem. For those, we just put a comment and mark the question for closure. I realize that you can't comment yet, but you should delete this answer and focus on posting good answers to good questions.

Comment: I didn't copy the whole thing but the closing part was there and I edited it so can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: Is there any extra information in the console? try setting the filter to show everything.  Your code works perfectly for me. Also, in your snippet, jQuery hasn't been included - if this is the same as your project then that's the problem.

Comment: Yap that was it thank you everyone!!

Answer (score -1):

I think the best option is to use id to call the element:

```
<div id="data_id" class="dataprocess"></div>
```

and then JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($( "#data_id" ).hasClass( "dataprocess" )){
        console.log("working");
    }
});
```

Comment: "best" option?  Sounds opinion based and will depend on the scenario.  Very few cases need an `id` and some pureist will state you should *never* use an `id`.